# Asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, imap

I am here just trying to download the emails in "INBOX" from the server using IMAP with ComponentPro .net component ([Asynchronous Task-Based Approach](http://www.componentpro.com/doc/mail/Downloading-Mail-Message-Asynchronously.htm)) but it throws the error every time when I try Asynchronous method.

I already got Inbox emails downloaded using IMAP with Synchronous approach but this takes nearly 3-4 minutes to download atleast 80+ emails, So I want to try asynchronous approach any suggestions on this as I am trying asynchronous approach for the first time.

Error:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.

Controller Code:

```
     public ActionResult ImportEmailDemo()
    {
        var sImportedEmails = ARepository.ImportEmailForDemo();
        return null;
    }
```

Repository Code:

```
    public async Task<string> ImportEmailForDemo()
    {
        //Async
        // Create a new instance of the Imap class.
        Imap client1 = new Imap();

        // Connect to the server.
        client1.Connect("Server Address");

        // Or you can specify the IMAP port with 
        // client.Connect("myserver", 143); 

        // Login to the server.
        client1.Authenticate("EmailID", "Password");


        // Select 'INBOX' mailbox.
        client1.Select("INBOX");

        // Download a mail message with sequence number 1.

        ComponentPro.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = await client1.DownloadMailMessageAsync(1);

        // ...

        Console.WriteLine("Message downloaded successfully.");
        Console.WriteLine("Message ID: {0}, Subject: {1}", msg.MessageIdentifier, msg.Subject);

        // Disconnect.
        client1.Disconnect();
        return null;
    }
```

I tried with different ways to resolve the error looking in internet but nothing worked for me, Can any one help me out.
Cheers!!

Comment: The problem is in your calling method. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Ok, I have added the controller code from where I am calling it.

Comment: @pavan FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen software. TY

Answer (score 2):

> I already got Inbox emails downloaded using IMAP with Synchronous approach but this takes nearly 3-4 minutes to download atleast 80+ emails, So I want to try asynchronous approach

Asynchronous won't be any faster.

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time.

This error occurs when your code starts an asynchronous operation within a synchronous handler. You should *not* be using `Wait` or `Result`; instead, you need to `await` the returned task, which makes that method `async`, etc., until your handler is changed to be asynchronous.

But as noted above, using `async` is not going to make it faster anyway.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the info, then do you know any best .Net component(dll) which can download emails faster then the one I am using here?

Comment: @pavan: Since downloading is an I/O-based operation, your speed is probably limited by the email server.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I have changed my mind to use synchronous one .